# How do I convert a 8760x2 DataFrame to a 365x25 DataFrame with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a 8760x2 pandas DataFrame which has the following data:

```
 [Datetime]...[Value]
 01-01-2019 00:00...1
 01-01-2019 01:00...1
 etc.
```

into a 365x25 DataFrame:

```
 [Date]...[hour 0]...[hour 1]...until [hour 23]
 01-01-2019...1...1...etc.
 etc.
```

I already made this:

```
Date= pd.DataFrame(df.drop_duplicates(subset='Date'))
Date= pd.DataFrame(Date.Date)

Newdf = pd.DataFrame()
for i in arange(0, 24):
    if i == 0:
        Newdf.insert(0, "Date", Date['Date'])
    Newdf.insert(int(i), "hour "+str(i), NaN*len(Newdf))
```

I get NaNs instead of Numbers. The date should also be checked, because sometimes I have the problem of a leap-year and time change (summertime, wintertime)...

What is the best method to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Split Datetime into date and time, and then do df.pivot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df['Date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.date
df['Hour'] = df['Datetime'].dt.hour

df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Hour', values='Value')
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. I guess this is because of wintertime / summertime...

Comment: That means your data contains duplicated entry on `datetime`, or in pairs `date, hour`. You can use `pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Hour', values='Value', aggfunc='sum')`.

Comment: But else it worked great. I have removed the duplicates. Don't know how to replace them though, but this was not the question in the first place, so thank you very much for the answer! :)

Comment: Glad that you found the problem. Interesting idea on winter/summer time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I will try aggfunc!